# Select query using the result (columns from the select from Info_schema)

Tags: mysql, sql-server

I need to copy/ insert all values with a certain where clause from table A to table B (basically from Main tables to respective history tables).

I don't want to specify the column names as I want to create a generic approach which will be able to use for all the tables that will need the ingestion.

Unfortunately, the attributes in table A are not always in the same order as it is in tableB, so I can't use select * into #temp from TableA and then insert into tableB from #temp. Plus TableB has generic 3 sys columns which we are generated for audit purposes.

My idea was to use the Info schema to get the column names. Then somehow use the result to get all the values from the asking table and add on top the generic sys columns. Is it possible to do?

I got the column names by using Info schema.

```
Select 
      COLUMN_NAME 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.columns
where TABLE_NAME = 'TableA'
```

The SYS columns are:

```
 sys_date=Getdate ()
,sys_flag='1'
,sys_name=SYSTEM_USER
```

Comment: Does the 2 table always have the column with same name, datatype and values, expect for the ordinal position.? All the additional column are same for all tables?

Comment: For starters....mysql or sql server? They are NOT the same thing. And once you decide which DBMS you are using you are going to need to clarify this question. It isn't clear to me what you are trying to do.

Comment: @RohitKumar, yes, two tables have the same datatypes. The only difference between two is that second one doesn't have constraints and have some additional columns.

Comment: @SeanLange. It is SQLserver

Comment: @valerie-kozel Thanks for confirming, please refer my answer.

Comment: @valerie-kozel  Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Use Dynamic Query SQL Server** 
Please change table Name accordingly.

```
Declare @Table_Name varchar(50)
SET @Table_Name ='LoginMst'
Declare @Query varchar(8000)
Declare @ColumnNames varchar (8000)
set @ColumnNames = ''
    select @ColumnNames = 
    case when @ColumnNames = ''
    then column_name
    else @ColumnNames + coalesce(',' + column_name, '')
    end
    from information_schema.columns where Table_Name=@Table_Name

SET @Query='insert into '+@Table_Name+'_Log ('+@ColumnNames+',sys_date,sys_flag,sys_name'+')
select '+@ColumnNames+',Getdate(),''1'',SYSTEM_USER from '+ 'LoginMst'
--print @Query
Exec(@Query)
```

You will require iterating all the tables you wish to take backup of. You will require adding the where clause too.

Comment: @valerie-kozel My pleasure, it served your purpose, if you can mark the answer as accepted, it would also help other looking for a similar issue.